# Azure cron expression for once every hour starting at specific time

Tags: azure, cron

I'm trying to create scheduled job, using cron expression but Azure is not accepting any of the expression I create.  For example I want to start a job that runs every hour starting at 3:30

0 30 3/1 * * * *

But according to Azure this is invalid.  According to other sites this is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean every hour starting from 3:30am and ending at midnight (11:30pm) every day?

This should work:

```
0 30 3-23 * * *
```

Or from 3:30pm to 11:30pm:

```
0 30 15-23 * * *
```

Update:
If you want your first run to happen at a specific time and then recur every n minutes, then Azure Webjob Cron won't help, I think. They do not support extended syntax. In fact, they use modified ncrontab implementation, so you can try to dig into that.

But - if you have a specific need to start cron at a specific time and run indefinetely, you have several options:
Option 1: Use [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs). It has `Start At Specific Time Setting`
Option 2: Add a check to your code that will check date/time and then run Cron every 30 minutes.

Comment: well actually I want the job to run continuously every hour forever, I just want the initial run to start at a specific time.

Comment: what if I don't care about the initial start time, but just want it to run every hour - basically I need to run it every hour over the full day, every day - is this right?  0 0 0-23 * * *

Answer (score 0):

You could separate clearing/setting an inhibition flag into separate jobs:

```
0 30 * * * * if [ ! -e /tmp/inhibitor ] ; then job.sh ; fi
0 0  0 * * * touch /tmp/inhibitor
0 29 3 * * * rm -f /tmp/inhibitor
```